# Knife Google Plugin setup issue

Tags: chef-infra, google-compute-engine, knife

I am trying to replicate the demo illustrated in   [Using Chef with Google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-video-demo-chef) . But I get the following error when I type in the command **knife google setup**.

```
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2104:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate googleauth-0.4.1, because multi_json-1.11.2 conflicts with multi_json (= 1.11) (Gem::ConflictError)
```

Kindly help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Gemspec needs to be more relaxed, setting it with '=' is not the best idea. 
Looking into blame, this was fixed a month ago:
https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby/commit/0e2b722d5b6c9fae190bfbd1244b144061886ac6

Author needs to cut a new gem for it, there's an issue raised:
https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby/issues/41

UPDATE: The [new gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/googleauth/versions/0.4.2) has been released, should be fixed now! :)

Comment: Thank you for answering Temikus. Is there any work around that I could use ? until the issue is solved?

Comment: I don't currently see an easy way to alleviate this, since this is not an internal project conflict, except for maybe building your own gem. But the new version should be cut soon, I'm currently chasing the maintainer.

Comment: The new gem is released and should be good to go! :) Please, let me know if you still have issues.